# AWS Elastic Beanstalk: Environment must have an instance profile associated with it

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-sdk

I am trying to create an environment in Elastic Beanstalk and here is my code for that:

```
AWSElasticBeanstalk client = AWSElasticBeanstalkClientBuilder.defaultClient(); 
    CreateEnvironmentRequest createEnvironmentRequest = new CreateEnvironmentRequest()
                    .withApplicationName("MySampleApplicationFour")
                    .withEnvironmentName("MySampleApplicationFour-env")
                    .withCNAMEPrefix("MySampleApplicationFour")
                    .withSolutionStackName("64bit Amazon Linux 2017.03 v2.5.1 running Java 8")
                    ;

            CreateEnvironmentResult result = client.createEnvironment(createEnvironmentRequest);
            System.out.println(result);
```

The above code executes successfully and print output as below:

```
{
EnvironmentName: MySampleApplicationFour - env,
EnvironmentId: e - bt6ric3q8g,
ApplicationName: MySampleApplicationFour,
SolutionStackName: 64bit Amazon Linux 2017.03 v2.5.1 running Java 8,
PlatformArn: arn: aws: elasticbeanstalk: ap - south - 1::platform / Java 8 running on 64bit Amazon Linux / 2.5.1,
CNAME: MySampleApplicationFour.ap - south - 1.elasticbeanstalk.com,
DateCreated: Tue Jul 11 13: 29: 41 IST 2017,
DateUpdated: Tue Jul 11 13: 29: 41 IST 2017,
Status: Launching,
Health: Grey,
Tier: {
    Name: WebServer,
    Type: Standard,
    Version:
},
EnvironmentLinks: []
}
```

But when I see the AWS Beanstalk console it is showing Environment as **terminated**.

Here is my AWS console:

[image: console screen]

Can anyone tell me how to create running environment in AWS Elastic Beanstalk?

Comment: The error says "Environment must have an instance profile associated with it". This might be relevant: [Service Roles, Instance Profiles, and User Policies](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/concepts-roles.html)

Comment: When I use AWS console it is working fine. When I do this through JAVA API I am getting this error.

Comment: The page I referenced suggests that you first create the environment via the console because it creates the IAM Roles and EC2 Instance Profiles automatically. If you launch an Elastic Beanstalk cluster totally via the API, you will need to create a Role and Instance Profile first for use the the Beanstalk environment.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Thanks for your response.. Even though if I create Role and Instance profile either by AWS Console or API, how would I associate those Instance profile to the Beanstalk environment that I am creating programatically. I didnt find any methods related to that like, `CreateEnvironmentRequest createEnvironmentRequest = new CreateEnvironmentRequest().withInstanceProfile().etc...`or something else.

Comment: I have also created Instance profile and policies with full access, but still I am getting the same result when I tried to create environment through API. Is there any example or sample code snippet for this.

Answer (score 0):

You Just try to change the Region which you are using for AWSClient builder and try to create environment.

Comment: It works for me. Previously I am using Mumbai region and now I changed it to Singapore and it works. But why it is not working with Mumbai region? 
 @nithyananth m